# Why redirect method is not working when rendering ejs file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am working on node.js can you tell why redirect method is not working? I 
  have a code in ejs file that call order(get method) route in app.js.

Code under app.js:

```
app.get('/order', routes.auth,routes.order);
```

Code under index.js:

```
exports.auth = function (req, res, next) {
if (req.session.authenticated) {
next();
} else {
res.redirect('signin');
}
};
```

Why redirect method is not go to signin.ejs file?it is always shown 404 not 
  found message even signin page available.In express 3 version redirect method
  will support or not?can any one clarify this? 
  And also please tell me the difference between of render and redirect.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Do you have `signin` route?

Comment: You just need a forward slash in front of 'signin', i.e. res.redirect('/signin')

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here: http://expressjs.com/api.html (EDIT: or here, since you seem to be using Express 3: http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html)

`redirect` redirects the user's browser to another address. That means, for example, that if the user goes to 'myadress.com/redirect-me', and you redirect him to '/i-was-redirected', he will go to 'myadress.com/i-was-redirected'.

`render` is used to show a template (for example `.ejs`) at the current address the browser is at.

If you only have an `.ejs` file, you probably want `render`. But I would recommend making a `signin` route and redirecting there instead.

Comment: yes i did the same i made signin route and i redirected there but still shown 404 not found.

Comment: What is the address of your signin route? Perhaps you want to use `/signin` instead. You can read how the relative redirects work in the documentation.

Comment: app.get("/signin",routes.signin); i did like this

Comment: it's not shown 404 error sorry.It is showing This webpage has a redirect loop..i don't understand what it is?

Comment: That means the site also redirects to something, and it creates and endless loop of redirections. Perhaps in the `signin` route you're also redirecting to itself, or some other route?

Comment: Are you redirecting to anything in the `signin` route? If so, then don't do that.

Comment: yes,i did like this exports.signin=function(req,res){
  res.redirect('signin');
}

Comment: Well, how do you expect that to work? You are redirecting from `/signin` to `/signin`. Perhaps you want to use render there instead? Try reading the documentation and some tutorials.

Comment: ok.. thank you.I used render method too but  it is showing !DOCTYPE html> >> 2| <html lang="en"> 3| <head> 4| <script src="../js/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 5| <% include templates/head.ejs%>

Comment: This error is shown..it's not render signin.ejs file ok anyhow thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define views directory and engine to use? if not add these lines and check

`app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` // setting engine

`app.set('views', path to your ejs files directory)`